# Verify that user input is compatible with SQL double(size,d) type?

Tags: php

A user types a number which is stored in `$num_str`. I need to check (using PHP) that the`$num_str` strictly matches the SQL format `double(9,2)`. In other words, check that

1. `$num_str` is of type `float` (i.e. `double`)
2. `$num_str` contains from 1 to 9 digits in total
3. `$num_str`contains 2 decimal places (i.e. two digits after the period `.`); if it does not, then trailing 0 must be appended after the decimal point. However, if *such concatenation would violate condition 2., then an error must be printed.*

Here is what I tried:

```
// 1.
if ( filter_var($num_str, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) === false ) echo "Invalid input";

// 2.
$num_str_nodecimal = str_replace(".", "", $num_str); // remove decimal point
if ( strlen($num_str_nodecimal) > 9 ) echo "Invalid number length";

// 3.
if ( strlen(substr(strrchr($num_str, "."), 1)) != 2 ) // less or more than 2 decimal places
   ???
```

What I am having trouble at is implementing step 3. Any ideas on how to do this elegantly and efficiently? Any native PHP methods for that? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try matching against a regular expression. You can try something like this:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{1,7}\.\d\d$/', $num_str) === 1) {
    // two decimals
} else if (preg_match('/^\d{1,7}\.\d$/', $num_str) === 1) {
    // one decimal
} else if (preg_match('/^\d{1,7}$/', $num_str) === 1) {
    // no decimals
} else {
    // input is invalid
}
```

These are important parts of the regular expression used:

- "^" - beginning of string
- "$" - end of string
- "\d" - a digit character
- "." - a point character (just "." represents any character in regex, backslash escapes it)
- "{1,7}" - match the character 1 to 7 times